# sorting set of varibables and giving points based on place

Tags: python, sorting

Just starting out with python, but cant figure out how to do this easily. 
Sorry if its a really basic question.

I got a class "players" with player.score as one of the variables. Is there a way to sort the players based on their score and store the place they get

```
pl1.score = 3
pl2.score = 2
pl3.score = 3
pl4.score = 0
```

I figured out this, but that only sort the scores, and dont give me the plX "key"

```
result_list(sorted([pl1.score, pl2.score, pl3.score, pl4.score], reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` parameter of the `sorted` function to add a comparison method.

```
players = [pl1,pl2,pl3,pl4]
places_players = sorted(enumerate(players),key=lambda i_p:i_p[1].score,reverse=True)
places = [i+1 for i,p in places_players]
print(places)
```

Output:

```
[1,3,2,4]
```

Comment: `[p for p in [pl1,pl2,pl3,pl4]]` is the same as `[pl1,pl2,pl3,pl4]`

Comment: test=sorted([pl1,pl2,pl3,pl4],key=lambda p:p.score,reverse=True)
    print(test)

Produced this:
[<__main__.player object at 0x05435610>, <__main__.player object at 0x05437F70>, <__main__.player object at 0x05435210>, <__main__.player object at 0x054372D0>]

Comment: So what do you want? The number after the `pl` ?

Comment: I want to use the sorted list to save what place each player gets in like pl1.first pl1.second etc. Its a simulation Im runing a number of times.

Answer (score 0):

If ordering of class objects is always by score, I believe there is a better approach.

Define your logic for ordering within your class. At a minimum, you should specify `__eq__` and `__lt__` operations for this to work. Then just use `sorted(lst_of_Player_instances)`.

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.score == other.score

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.score > other.score
```